# Open folder button in streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

I have built a streamlit application which reads a file and processes it and stores it in a file folder which is already defined.

Now I want to create a button in streamlit where after file is processed it should display a button, which on click opens the respective folder.
Screenshot for reference:
[image]

I tried using `st.markdown` and `st.link_button` but it is not opening the folder.
Here is what I tried:

```
###method 1:
st.link_button("Go to Folder", r"C:\path\to\Output_file")

###method 2:
url = r"C:\path\to\Output_file"
st.markdown(f'''
        <a href={url}><button style="background-color:GreenYellow;">Go To Folder</button></a>
        ''',unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

It isn't working. Is there any workaround for this?

I saw a few articles where people are suggesting to use Tkinter, but how to implement that to open folder. or are there any other suitable options.

if not streamlit then is there any other application which can do it?

Comment: Currently streamlit does not support file/folder browsing. What are your process flow after opening the folder? You want to get the path of file?, etc?

Comment: @ferdy I just wanted to add the open folder option as a convenience for the user to see the output folder, instead of manually opening the file explorer and navigating to the folder.

Comment: try this lib https://github.com/pragmatic-streamlit/streamlit-file-browser